# google sheets adding rows and keeping referece unchanged

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a function that would grab a list of dates from a tab named div and make an array of the years:

```
=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(YEAR(FILTER(div!H2:H,ISBLANK(div!H2:H)=FALSE))))
```

The problem is when I add a row or multiple rows in the div tab, the whole reference in the formula  is shifted, so if I add one row, the formula will become as follow:

```
=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(YEAR(FILTER(div!H3:H,ISBLANK(div!H3:H)=FALSE))))=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(YEAR(FILTER(div!H3:H,ISBLANK(div!H3:H)=FALSE))))
```

I tried locking the refence using the $ sign, and wraping the refences using indirect() formula, but its not working.
Any idea how to fix this issue ?

Thanks

i tried indirect fuction as following:

```
=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(YEAR(FILTER(div!indirect(H2:H),ISBLANK(div!indirect(H2:H))=FALSE))))
```

Answer (score 0):

*Can you try:*

```js
=let(Σ,indirect("div!H2:H"),
     unique(filter(year(Σ),Σ<>"")))
```